# Do cells in healing ligaments or tendons have deformation processes? If so, what are they?

Tags: human-anatomy, muscles, regeneration

I am trying to better understand how non-muscle tissue in the muscuoloskeletal system heals. Specifically, I am interested in how ligaments or tendons heal once torn.

I read the following text:

> If the muscle pulls the damaged tendon and then releases it then we have a deformation cycle that the cells are able to detect. They also then receive the information they require regarding orientation. This is why the elasticity of the early callus is important; the tissue must be able to be pulled out and then return to its original shape in order to receive information about orientation.

Source: 
http://www.peraspenberg.com/texts/how-do-tendons-and-ligaments-heal/

I don't understand what they mean by "deformation cycle" and how cells detect it.

Is there a name for this cycle? If so, how do the cells detect tissue deformation?

Also, if there is any literature that specializes in the tissue of ligaments or tendons, recommendations would be appreciated. I have plenty on muscle tissue and some on bones, but not ligament or tendon tissue regeneration.

Comment: Are you asking about tendons or ligaments, or both? Your quote only discusses tendons. Your title only mentions ligament. And in the question's details you asked about "the tissue of ligaments *and* tendon formations"

Comment: You are correct, it was ambiguous. I updated it. Is it clearer?

Comment: Thanks, that's clearer. Why did you reject my edit? it was pretty much the same as yours and in addition to it was fixing tags, typos, and dead link.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Because I didn't read it clearly enough and did a bad job. If there was a way to resurrect your edit and do it again, I would approve it. At the time, I read the title and the first few lines, and it seemed to be changing the content. Then you called my attention to it again and I realized it was probably an experienced person editing it or they wouldn't care. When I reread it carefully, I realized you were right. I get a lot of edits that just make small changes, so I might have been trigger happy on reject.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Sorry about that :/